# How to load 16 x 8 bit integer using SSE2

Tags: x86, sse, simd, sse2

Suppose I have 16 of 8-bit integers and I want to load them into an `__m128i` using SSE2 as:

```
__m128i v = _mm_set_epi8(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);
```

I can do this statically using `_mm_set_epi8` but I would like to do this dynamically; the values will be decided during runtime.

```
C = userinput;
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
{
    load C*i on v at position i
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For a case like what you describe, but with 16-bit integers, use a constant like you're doing now (`set(1,2,3,4,...)`), and multiply that by `set1(user_input)`.  Broadcasting is easy / cheap, but there's no instruction for making a series in a register.  `_mm_set_epi8(C*1, C*2, ...)` would compile into a lot of scalar multiplies, on most compilers.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a union:

```
union {
    __m128i v;
    uint8_t a[sizeof(__m128i)];
} u;
```

Load your values into array a and then read the SSE vector back from v.

Alternatively if your data is already in contiguous memory then just use `_mm_load_si128` (or `_mm_loadu_si128` if you can't guarantee 16 byte alignment).

Comment: Perhaps you could replace `uint8_t a[16];` with `uint8_t a[sizeof(__m128i)];`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this question has been answered, but I know for sure that Paul R is right.

For contiguous data, use a load intrinsic

```
__m128i v = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&C[0]);
```

If your data isn't guaranteed to always be aligned, use `_mm_loadu_si128`.

Answer (score 2):

The values passed to `_mm_set_epi8` do not have to be constants -- in your example, you could perfectly well write

```
__m128i v = _mm_set_epi8(   0,    C,  2*C,  3*C,
                          4*C,  5*C,  6*C,  7*C,
                          8*C,  9*C, 10*C, 11*C,
                         12*C, 13*C, 14*C, 15*C);
```

(None of the compilers I have to hand does a great job with this, but it does work.)

Answer (score 0):

```
char Strings[10][1001];
char *gc="GC";  

*((__m128i*)gc)
```

and

```
*((__m128i*)(&(Strings[i][j])))
```

will also work if you'd rather do it that way.  I like the struct answer as well but if you're working with pointers into text you're generally going to have to cast and do pointer math.  (That's been my experience anyway.)